# If 'x' is in both files do y, if not, break?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7, numpy

I've got two files, one with just ID-numbers and the other with some of those ID-numbers along with their corresponding values (statistical info). I have a script that checks if the numbers are in both files then prints the numbers and values from the larger file. Unfortunately with my present script, I just get errors when it notices that things are 'out of range'. Furthermore, later in the script it tries to divide by zero I assume due to the values that aren't there (not in value-file). Here's the pertinent aspects of my script as is:

```
for j in range(len(data)/22):

  if(data[1+j*22][3]==stars[i][0]):
   name=str(data[1+j*22][1])
   dust=str(data[2+j*22][20])
```

I've tried this to no success:

```
for j in range(len(data)/22):
  if(data[1+j*22][3]!=stars[i][0]):
   print 'not available'
  elif(data[1+j*22][3]==stars[i][0]):
   name=str(data[1+j*22][1])
   dust=str(data[2+j*22][20])
```

Also this:

```
for j in range(len(data)/22):
  if(data[1+j*22][3]!=stars[i][0]):
   break
  elif(data[1+j*22][3]==stars[i][0]):
   name=str(data[1+j*22][1])
   dust=str(data[2+j*22][20])
```

And finally at the bottom, where it tries to divide by zero

```
print Temp
Teff=round(sum(Temp/chi)/sum(1/chi),0)
Tempin=round(sum(Tin/chi)/sum(1/chi),0)
tau=round(sum(Tau/chi)/sum(1/chi),5)
luminosity=round(sum(Luminosity/chi)/sum(1/chi),0) 
Massloss=round(sum(Mdot/chi)/sum(1/chi),3)
Chi=round(sum(chi)/len(chi),2)
```

where my 'chi' value is giving the problem (defined in script).

Here's the error I'm getting

```
if(data[1+j*22][3]!=stars[i][0]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I believe that if I can fix the initial data ranges I won't have to worry about the chi values being zero. I only mentioned it hoping that would give more clarification to my problem.

Trimmed code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import StringIO

#Read in the stars that will be selected from the set of models
#SCRIPT='/SAH/SAH5/user/Results/b3results/b3Over'
SCRIPT=raw_input('Star List file: Ex. /SAH/SAH5/user/Modeling/TestStars\n') 
stars=[]
f=open(SCRIPT,"rb") #Fill in the SCRIPT variable
for line in f:
 s=line.split()
 stars.append(s)
f.close()

#Read in the Models
#SCRIPTM='/SAH/SAH5/user/Results/b3/Filtered/NewModels'
SCRIPTM=raw_input('Uttenthaler output file: Ex. /SAH/SAH5/user/Modeling/chisquaretests/stars3\n')
data=[]
d=open(SCRIPTM,"rb") #Fill in the SCRIPT variable
for line in d:
 if not line.strip():
  continue
 else:
  s=line.split()
  data.append(s)

d.close()

NewResults=''


for i in range(len(stars)):
 print stars[i][0]
 chi=np.array([])
 Temp=np.array([])
 Tin=np.array([])
 Tau=np.array([])
 Luminosity=np.array([])
 Mdot=np.array([])
 #print len(data)
 for j in range(len(data)/22):

  if(data[1+j*22][3]==stars[i][0]):
   name=str(data[1+j*22][1])
   dust=str(data[2+j*22][20])

   #print data[2+j*22][4]
   chi=np.append(chi,float(data[2+j*22][4]))
   chi=np.append(chi,float(data[3+j*22][4]))
   chi=np.append(chi,float(data[4+j*22][4]))
   chi=np.append(chi,float(data[5+j*22][4]))
   chi=np.append(chi,float(data[6+j*22][4]))


 print Temp
 Teff=round(sum(Temp/chi)/sum(1/chi),0)
 Tempin=round(sum(Tin/chi)/sum(1/chi),0)
 tau=round(sum(Tau/chi)/sum(1/chi),5)
 luminosity=round(sum(Luminosity/chi)/sum(1/chi),0)
 Massloss=round(sum(Mdot/chi)/sum(1/chi),3)
 Chi=round(sum(chi)/len(chi),2)

 NewResults=NewResults+str(int(stars[i][0]))+'\t'+name+'\t'+str(Teff)+'\t'+str(Tempin)+'\t'+dust+'\t'+str(tau)+'\t'+str(luminosity)+'\t'+str(Massloss)+'\t'+str(Chi)+'\n'

print NewResults
```

[This](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5913238) is my stars3 file, That is the 'chunk' of data for one of the integer values in the other file. Here it's in the 'Name' row: '6973'. TestStars is simply a single column of numbers: 6239, 7010, etc. No commas, just pure integers.

Comment: Are you getting an `IndexError` or a `ZeroDivisionError` here? Your description seems to imply both, but that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: I've received that error previously. I've been trying in desperation to get this to work and have forgotten everything attempted.

Comment: Is there any way you can strip this down to something small enough to post complete code and source data that still exhibits the problem (i.e., an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))? That will make the problem a lot easier to debug. As it is, we need to do a lot of guessing, and can't even be sure that the problem is in the fragment of code you've shown us, so you're going to get a lot less attention.

Comment: @abarnert See edit. That's pretty much the whole code I just removed some things that are utilized under the `print Temp` section. Thanks for the assistance/attention.

Comment: Without sample `TestStars` and `stars3` files, we still can't test anything.

Comment: Meanwhile, if this is trimmed to the minimal code that shows the problem… what's the point of all those `Temp=np.array([])`, etc. lines? You never use those values (except to `print Temp`, which is just going to print an empty array).

Comment: Edited. As for the Temp=... that is defined much like the chi=np.append...I just removed that because those don't seem to be a problem (at least in my eyes).

Comment: Why remove the value when you can just remove the whole line? The whole point of stripping it down is to remove extraneous stuff that people have to rummage through to find possible problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things that I notice here.

If you do `data[1+j*22][3]` then you never access the zeroth member of the list, don't you want to access it?
Why do you even divide by 22 in the range decleration?

As for the zero division, then you use the len function on chi, but in the lines before that  you use chi as a divisor, so is chi a number or a list?

Comment: I have to divide by 22 because [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5913238) is my data file, only in full it's much longer. The other one is simply a single column of ID-numbers. I've run this code with minimal numbers assuring that they were in both files and it works great. I'd just like it to be able to ignore null values. Actually, you gave me the sinking feeling that this code (written by someone else unfortunately for me) isn't the only problem. I also think the code that produces the output (of the link) is also an issue. Crap.

Comment: It seems to me that you want to get all the lines that are indented in the data file and check if the number in column 2 there (11495, 11494, 10293 etc) are also in the test file.
Then you have to check if `data[j][2] == stars[i][0]`

Comment: Also, don't do `range(len(data)/22)`, I suppose you wanted to divide by 22 since there were 22 columns in each line, but that is not neccesery. the len(data) gives you how many lines there are, and if you divide by 22 you will loop through 22 less lines then there actually are.

Just do `range(len(data))`, that will let you loop through all lines.

Comment: That line particularly bothers me because if the ID-number isn't present in the file the Mod# lines don't show up either but EVERY other line (lines 9 through 22 in the data link) will show up, so I think that will make the program freakout no matter what.

Comment: This is a really buggy program, another thing is that when you create the data list then you populate it with elements from all lines, the `if not lines.strip():` has no effect and is never true so the `continue` statement never gets processed. To see if you are really at a line which begins with Mod# just do `if line[:3] == "Mod#"` provided that you have used strip on it before.

Comment: Thank you for all this help. I've been spending the better part of 2 weeks trying to get someone else's code working and it's driving me nuts.